# conditional tags not working correctly in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have the widget logic widget installed on my site. I am using the following code inside it

```
is_category(6) || is_page(array(1203, 1436, 1448))
```

However the widget does not show up for `page-id=1436, page-id=1448`

WHy is this happening?

Comment: what version of WP are you using? the array functionality was added to is_page() on version 2.5. Also note that is_page() doesn't work in the loop

Comment: @Matanya, Widgets don't happen in the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : Just checked the `is_page()` function in WordPress core and no : it does look into an array that can be an array of IDs (with `in_array`) (see wp-includes/query.php, line 3374). (array capability added in WordPress 2.5). As Matanya says, you have to use it outside the loop.